# Chartjs Barchart without borders

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am trying to build a barchart with chartjs where there should be no space between neighbouring bars. The problem i have is that I don't get rid of the borders between the bars:
[Bars with borders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FurQa.png)

This is my config:

```
new Chart($('#weekly-availabilities-chart'), {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
  labels: ...,
  datasets: [
    {
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(153, 193, 72, 0.4)',
      label: 'label a',
      borderWidth: 0,
      data: dataset_1
    }, {
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(13, 39, 73, 0.4)',
      label: 'label b',
      borderWidth: 0,
      data: dataset_2
    }
  ]
},
  options: {
  scales: {
    xAxes: [
      {
        barPercentage: 1,
        categoryPercentage: 1,
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        }
      }
    ],
    yAxes: [
      {
        stacked: true,
        gridLines: {
          color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.05)'
        },
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          max: 40
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
});
```

Comment: check this  https://jsfiddle.net/07pzys9t/2/

Answer (score 0):

use [borderWidth: 0](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#bar-chart-dataset-structure) in your datasets.

```
datasets: [
  {
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(153, 193, 72, 0.4)',
    label: 'label a',
    data: dataset_1,
    borderWidth: 0
  }, {
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(13, 39, 73, 0.4)',
    label: 'label b',
    data: dataset_2,
    borderWidth: 0
  }
]
```

Comment: I tried, but it does not hava any effect. I will update my question including this option.

Comment: Did you find a solution?